# EditText get value to pass Textview

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I am working on an activity in which I have taken edittext and textview. I have to get integer value from edittext and set it on textview.

I have to take 10-digit number(mobile no) on edittext and as soon as the edittext column gets 10-digits,its automatically sets 10-digit number on textview within the same activity.

I have implemented in this manner

1. Getting value on edittext using

   ```
   Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
   ```

   in a String str.
2. Applying condition to it `(str.length == 10)` and getting it on textview.

As the above process is not working so try to help me friends.

I am working on this code:

```
public class MobileNo extends Activity {

        EditText et;
        TextView tv;
        int i;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

            et.getText().toString();

            et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable textVal) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Editable inputNo = textVal;
                    if (inputNo.length() == 10) {
                        tv.setText(inputNo);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not working? what is the issue you face?

Comment: I have to get 10-digit mobile number from edittext into textview without clicking on anything. As soon as edittext takes 10-digit its automatically sets those 10-digits on textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable textVal) {
                String inputNo = textVal.toString();
                if (inputNo.length() == 10) {
                    tv.setText(inputNo);
                }

            }
```

If your phone number is formatted like "(800) 549-2992" or "800-549-2992" and you only wants the numbers then you'd have to do the following:

```
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable textVal) {
                // takes out all non-digits from string
                String inputNo = textVal.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
                if (inputNo.length() == 10) {
                    tv.setText(inputNo);
                }

            }
```

Comment: you might want to try putting the code in `onTextChanged` instead